# ZF2 - How to set a cookie inside a model?

Tags: zend-framework2

I try to set a cookie inside a model but it not seems to work. Any idea?

```
$header = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie();
$header->setName('Token');
$header->setValue($token);
$header->setPath('/');
$header->setDomain('localhost');
$header->setExpires(time()+(3600*24*365));

$client = new \Zend\Http\Client();
$client->addCookie($header);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add the header to the HTTP response object, not a random instance of HTTP client.

The model is probably not the right place for this though. Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, I'd suggest returning the token instead, so you can set this cookie in the controller action.